# Sql query returns empty. But not

Tags: sql

my sql query returns empty

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from table1 WHERE id = ' .$bransId);
```

And im sure that $bransId is not empty. ( i checked)

Comment: Did you define global $wpdb? Does the table1 exist? Does the id exist in that table?

Answer (score 0):

If you can answer 'yes' to the questions in Emetrop's comment, then try:

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from table1 WHERE id = $bransId');
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work, since the variable isn't inside double quotes. Additionally we shouldn't trust the user input and use `$wpdb->prepare()`.